# No default Radio button selected

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I need a dialog like this

[image]

but I can't find the way to do a `RadioButton` dialog with no option selected by default. I try with a null where you select the default button, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(titulo)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dlgRadiobuttonsListener.seleccionadoRB(DlgRadiobuttons.this, getResources().getStringArray(items)[which]);
            }
        });

    return builder.create();        
}
```

Comment: make the 2nd param -1 so that no one gets selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of setSingleChoiceItems is the index of the item to be selected, passing -1 will make android to not select anyone.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(titulo)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dlgRadiobuttonsListener.seleccionadoRB(DlgRadiobuttons.this, getResources().getStringArray(items)[which]);
            }
        });

    return builder.create();

}
```